# how to set Image and text at the center of the button

Tags: android

i have set my buttons width to `fill_parent`.

so Is it possible to set Image and text at center of button.

there is option for `drawable_Left` but it aligns image on left side of button...

I want something like this.

---

.... [image][text]....  |

---

Thanks:

Comment: after using drawable_Left you can set padding

Answer (score 2):

Try this: first set background for the button then set image by using `android:drawableTop=""` and then set the text by `android:text=""`

Answer (score 0):

use `android:gravity="center_vertical"` in your layout

Answer (score 0):

first give the `gravity` to `center` then use `drawable_Left`.

Answer (score 0):

your should you Relative layout for getting the solution of your problem using the blow code put it on your xml file

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal ="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="200dp" android:gravity="center"></Button>
```

Hope it helps ;

Answer (score 0):

Here is an utility function to center a left image and text inside a `Button`:

```
public static void centerImageAndTextInButton(Button button) {
    Rect textBounds = new Rect();
    //Get text bounds
    CharSequence text = button.getText();
    if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
        TextPaint textPaint = button.getPaint();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(text.toString(), 0, text.length(), textBounds);
    }
    //Set left drawable bounds
    Drawable leftDrawable = button.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
    if (leftDrawable != null) {
        Rect leftBounds = leftDrawable.copyBounds();
        int width = button.getWidth() - (button.getPaddingLeft() + button.getPaddingRight());
        int leftOffset = (width - (textBounds.width() + leftBounds.width()) - button.getCompoundDrawablePadding()) / 2 - button.getCompoundDrawablePadding();
        leftBounds.offset(leftOffset, 0);
        leftDrawable.setBounds(leftBounds);
    }
}
```

It uses the width of the `Button` to make the calculation, so you **must** check that you are calling this in the right place. That is, the width should be other than zero. For instance, if you want to use it in `onCreate` use `button.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(...call it onGlobalLayout...)`.